# И еще по Стругацким

Tags: литература, ономастика

И еще один вопрос о значении слов в творчестве Стругацких. А интересует меня кличка кота в "За миллион лет до конца света" — Калям. Что это за слово вообще такое?

Comment: Был какой-то сайт в Интернете, где ещё несколько лет назад сам Борис Натанович Стругацкий отвечал на подобные вопросы от читателей. В 2012 году Б.Н.Стругацкого не стало. Но возможно этот сайт ещё можно найти поисковиком. Адреса не помню. Там было много разных интересных вопросов и ответов.

Answer (score 1):

А еще один - это где предыдущие?

Про Каляма - не в курсе. Нет оснований предпологать, что оно вообще что-то значит. Возможно анаграмма от "маляка".

Т.е. слова с таким звучанием есть: 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC  
И, видимо, даже не одно. 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC
Но какая тут связь с котом - совершенно не понятно.